# Authentication database name must only contain letters, numbers, underscores and dashes while using $external for AD authentication

Tags: java, mongodb, authentication, spring-data

Getting below error while while authenticating against AD for Mongo DB using spring data, authentication database value is $external, it works well against admin database which is local to Mongo. Also, authentication against $external works from Mongo shell.

Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Authentication database name must only contain letters, numbers, underscores and dashes!

Is using the Java mongo driver the solution or is there any option with spring data?

Comment: um.. did you check if the name had in-valid characters in it?

Comment: Its valid value works from Mongo Shell.

Comment: Could you post the name?

Comment: $external is the value for AD authentication database. Below is the command that works from mongo shell, but the doesn't work from Spring data.                                                                                             mongo --host localhost --port 27001 -u testapp_write -p password --authenticationDatabase "$external" --authenticationMechanism PLAIN

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found root cause for this. Spring data doesn't accept special chars for authentication database name. I ended up authenticating against admin (local to Mongo) instead of external AD/LDAP. Hope this helps someone.